# Finding usage of resources (CPU and memory) by threads of a process in Android

Tags: android, resources, pthreads

I have a multi-threaded application(C++,C and pthread library) and I will like to know how much resources(CPU and memory) each thread uses. Is there a way to find out these details on Android?

I have tried

```
$ adb shell ps -p -t
```

But, this gives information in the below format,

```
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS   PRIO  NICE  RTPRI SCHED   WCHAN    PC         NAME

root      1     0     476    312   20    0     0     0     c037c0e0 000087bc S /init

root      2     0     0      0     20    0     0     0     c031f114 00000000 S kthreadd

root      3     2     0      0     20    0     0     0     c030e5d0 00000000 S ksoftirqd/0

root      4     2     0      0     -100  0     99    1     c033fc50 00000000 S watchdog/0

root      5     2     0      0     20    0     0     0     c031b4b4 00000000 S events/0

root      6     2     0      0     20    0     0     0     c031b4b4 00000000 S khelper
```

Any way to know which threads are running along with their parent's id will be really helpful.

using

```
$ adb logcat -v threadtime
```

prints info about the running process (PID) and the thread (TID).
But, its not enough for my purpose. I want to know how much resources is a particular thread consuming. Any pointers.

Comment: i think no answer to this question! i have already moved on, by solving my problem.. but still this question is unanswered. How to close the question without an answer?? Moderators please help.

Answer (score 1):

ps command in android seems to be very limited compared to linux.

You could try:

```
ps -t -c APP_NAME
```

This will show you threads(-t) and the CPU assigned to the thread (-c)

Example:

```
ps -t -c -p com.whatsapp
```

-p is thread priority(linux nice value)